# Passing parameter among three forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, delegates, parameter-passing

I have application which has three form: 1, 2, 3
- Form1: Always visible and has a button btnLogin. When I click on btnLogin, Form2 is opened.
- Form2: has 2 buttons: btnSearch and btnAddNew. When I click on btnAddNeww, Form3 is opened.
- Form3: has two text box and a button: txtA.text, txtB.text and btnOK. If I click on btnOK, two string in two text boxs will pass to Form1.
How can I do that, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your textboxes access modifiers in Form1 public (you can see this on properties of textbox):

[image]

Then you can call them directly using:

```
Form1 frm1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
frm1.txtBox1.Text = txtA.Text + txtB.Text;
```

Comment: Good to hear that @HuuTin :)